# Up navigation button does not work in basic Android Application without custom toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

I' have a problem with the app toolbar UP button which never passes the `R.id.home` on the  `onOptionsItemSelected` method when pressed in a child activity.

The main activity

```
package com.foocorp.firstapp;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class InstrumentListActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements IUdpNotificationListener
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.home) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Menu back from Main", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Hard back from Main", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
}
```

The child activity where I set the `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

```
package com.foocorp.firstapp;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class InstrumentViewDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IUdpNotificationListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_instrument_view_details);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        //whatever here
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_instrument_view_details, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        //=> never get called because passed ID is never R.id.home
        if (id == R.id.home) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Menu back from Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            finish();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Hard back from Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // this works fine
        finish();
    }

}
```

The manifest file where the parent child relation is defined

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.foocorp.firstapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_tap_and_play_white_24dp"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="com.foocorp.firstapp.InstrumentListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".InstrumentViewDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/instrum_details"
            android:parentActivityName="com.foocorp.firstapp.InstrumentListActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.foocorp.firstapp.InstrumentListActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The menu layout file of the child activity (by the way, is it normal that the UP button is not defined here although it appears when the application is running ?)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.foocorp.firstapp.InstrumentViewDetailsActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

While searching the internet for this solution, I have found the tips about the parent/child relation in the manifest file and the `getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);` but despite theses hints, I can't get this UP toolbar button to work properly : it DOES return to the parent activity BUT not in the proper way like when I press the back button wich calls the `onBackPressed()` method and which works fine.

Any clue about what I'm missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change id of back button from
`R.id.home` to `android.R.id.home` in your `onOptionsItemSelected()` Method.

you can also use `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);` instead of `finish();` as you have mentioned `parentActivityName` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: That's it !! Many thanks... I was about to go crazy... But this is odd, right ? What does the "android" namespace represents exactly here ?

Comment: btw the 'finish()' method works just fine so I'm gonna stick with it. But your remarks is duly noted :)

Comment: you have used R.id.home so android search back button with id home in your project but we have to use default back button provided by android so we use default back button id which is in android namespace so we have to use android.R.id.home